# Android Junit Testing Freezes

Tags: android, junit, test-suite

I have an android app that I am unit testing. I have 4 test classes each with multiple test methods. I run them all at the same time from a test suite. I ran into a problem on the emulator where the test would just freeze in the middle of running the tests. I switched to using an actual device and the problem went away.

Fast forward a few weeks and I'm not having the same problem while running tests on my device. I have been on Google for the last couple days trying to find a solution but nothing I have found has helped.

**The Issue**
When I try to run all the tests the test will freeze eventually. And by freeze I mean the test itself freezes. I saw one solution that it might be the phone or eclipse. I restarted my phone, updated everything in eclipse including eclipse itself. I tried changing views to see if maybe the eclipse view was not refreshing but none of that helped. I also tried using the junit v4 library instead of v3.

If I run the test methods individually they all run and pass. Its only when I run them all from the test suite that they fail.

**The Log**
I checked the log and this is what I get:
`03-13 12:11:04.526: I/TestRunner(23175): started: testCheckShowDialogEnabled(com.package.name.MainActivityTest)`

after that there is nothing else in the log.

**On The Device**
The app is finished and is removed from the screen. It it not reopened again at the beginning of the next test.

**The Code**
Here is the code that I think might be relevant. If you need any more code just let me know.

```
public class AllTests extends TestSuite {
    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        suite.addTestSuite(MainActivityTest.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(DatabaseHandlerTest.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(ClassOneTest.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(AnotherActivityTest.class);

        return suite;
    }
}

public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super("com.package.name", MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();


        mMainActivity = getActivity();
        mSolo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), mMainActivity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();

        mMainActivity = null;
    }
    // all the test methods
}
```

All my test classes implement `setup()` and `tearDown()` similarly.

Anyone out there know why my tests keep freezing? Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/robotium-developers/5i3YoyYFpWE

Comment: i tried this in my tearDown() and now the JUnit view in eclipse appears to still be frozen at the second test method. However now in a period of about a second I get a started test, finished test, and passed test log entry for all my test methods.

Comment: If the tests can really run that quick I can believe the log but I have never had these tests run that quick. It usually has taken a couple minutes to finish them all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@smk pointed me in the direction to find a solution to this. I just changed my `tearDown()` to this:

```
@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mSolo.finishOpenActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}
```

Now it works great!